# What to call paragraph in relevant work chapter that explains relation to own thesis/research?

Tags: titles, literature-review

My second supervisor suggested that I add a final paragraph in my Relevant Work chapter which essentially explains why the discussed work is related to my own. I wrote the paragraph which explains this but also how my work differed from the discussed literature.

What should I call it? I stand at "Relation to my work" at the moment.

If more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a paragraph, then it probably doesn't need its own section title. You can leave it just as "a final paragraph", which is apparently what your second supervisor requested.

If it is more substantial than just one paragraph (maybe three or more), then it might deserve a section title. In that case, I would probably name it something like "Distinctiveness of [my work]". (I personally think literally writing "my work" is rather informal language for a scholarly work, but that's up to you and your supervisors to decide.) Note that rather than titling it "relatedness", I recommend you title it "distinctiveness"--you want to emphasize how your work is different from otherwise related work and how it goes beyond it.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it needs a title? You can just leave it as another paragraph in the same section.